# Sorting a matrix in descending order in C

Tags: c, sorting, matrix

I need to input a matrix, where the first element of a row is the student ID number, and the other 12 elements are student points and GPA. Each row represents one student. What the program needs to do is calculate the total point amount, and then sort the matrix so it goes in descending order by the amount of points.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number_of_students,i,j;
    double matrix[50][50],GPA,grades,total,GPA_before;

    printf("Number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_students);

    printf("Input students: ");
    for(i=0; i<number_of_students; i++){
        for(j=0; j<12; j++){
            scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Final list: \n");
    for(i=0; i<number_of_students; i++){
        GPA_before=(matrix[i][2]+matrix[i][3]+matrix[i][4]+matrix[i][5])*2.5;
        if(GPA_before==50){
            GPA=GPA_before+3;
        }
        else{
            GPA=GPA_before;
        }
        grades=(matrix[i][6]+matrix[i][7]+matrix[i][8]+matrix[i][9]+matrix[i][10]+matrix[i][11])*0.67;
        total=GPA+grades+matrix[i][12];

        printf("%d. %g | %g\n",i,matrix[i][1],total);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
Number of students: 4
Input students: 123456 4.00 4.50 5.00 5.00 5 5 5 4 4 5 15
456789 4.50 5.00 4.00 3.50 3 5 4 5 5 2 10
789321 5.00 5.00 4.50 3.00 5 4 5 3 5 3 15
456987 4.50 4.50 4.50 5.00 4 4 4 5 5 5 25
Final list: 
1. 123456 | 80.01
2. 456789 | 68.58
3. 789321 | 75.5
4. 456987 | 89.34
```

The matrix should be sorted from highest number of points to the lowest, not by ID. It is specified not to sort the list while printing it out, the matrix itself must be sorted.
I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Aside: Indices start from zero in C, not one. The idiom would be `for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)`. Using the form you've shown will start to cause problems when you want to place exactly *N* elements in an array of size *N*.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the input and output *as text* and format it as a code block.

Comment: @SupportUkraine thanks for the help, but I should solve it without using pointers.

Comment: Re "*I should solve it without using pointers*",  1) This means you can't use `scanf`. All of its arguments are pointers. `&` returns a pointer. 2) This means you'll have to write your own sorting code. You can't pass arrays to functions (only pointers to them), so all existing functions will use pointers.

Comment: @Bodo Alright, I will fix it. I'm new so I didn't know.

Comment: _"the first element of a row is the student ID number, and the other 12 elements are student points and GPA"_ - Have you used `struct` ? `struct student { int id; double scores[12]; };`

Comment: @SupportUkraine I understand you, but I am supposed to sort it using some kind of selection sort. What I mean is using more of the basic programming stuff.

Comment: @Tom If that's the case, can you please show your best attempt at implementing [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) in your program?

Comment: _"the other 12 elements are student points"_ - There are only 11 elements after the first, presumed, id element.

Comment: @Oka The thing is that I've only done it using arrays, and I am not sure how to use it in a matrix.

Comment: OK, so for those of you who are being pedantic about the pointers: 1.  This is a class assignment.  2.  Read "You can't use pointers" as "You can't use the asterisk."  3.  The OP is probably not allowed to use third-party routines like `qsort`.

Comment: To the OP: These kinds of questions are best directed to your professor, tutor or teaching assistant.  We're not in you're class, and we're not mind-readers, so we don't know exactly what your teacher's intent is.  We also can't provide tutoring here, and homework help is very limited.  Read [ask] for more information.

Comment: The input `123456 4.00 4.50 5.00 5.00 5 5 5 4 4 5 15` looks like an array of structures would better fit than a two-dimensional array. (If you already learnt about structures.) If you must use an array, using preprocessor symbols instead the hard coded index numbers might make the program easier to unserstand,e.g. `#define IDX_ID 0` `printf("%d. %g | %g\n",i,matrix[i][IDX_ID],total);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I saw a few things in your code that I would like to point out and change, if possible.

1. You are allocating an 2-D Array of 50 rows and 50 columns. However, you're only utilizing 12 of those columns. So, first thing that I would like you to fix is the use of those extra *unnecessary* array indexes. So, I wrote the following code:

```c
const int MAX = 50;
const int NUM_INPUTS = 12;
int number_of_students, i, j;
double matrix[MAX][NUM_INPUTS + 1], GPA, grades, total;
```

Note: I added `NUM_INPUTS + 1`, that we will use to store the total of that you were calculating in the loop and also printing it too.

Now, another thing I would like to point out, is your use of loops. You're iteration is beginning from the index `1`. You're not using the `0th` index. So, you'll have to fix each loop from this:

```c
for(i=1; i<=number_of_students; i++){
    for(j=1; j<=12; j++){
        scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

to this:

```c
for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_INPUTS; j++) {
        scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Now, this indexing from `0` will cause the code that you wrote for the calculations, to not work properly, so, you will have to fix that too:

```c
for(i=1; i<=number_of_students; i++){
    GPA_before=(matrix[i][2]+matrix[i][3]+matrix[i][4]+matrix[i][5])*2.5;
    if(GPA_before==50){
        GPA=GPA_before+3;
    }
    else{
        GPA=GPA_before;
    }
    grades=(matrix[i][6]+matrix[i][7]+matrix[i][8]+matrix[i][9]+matrix[i][10]+matrix[i][11])*0.67;
    total=GPA+grades+matrix[i][12];
```

You were using this code in-junction with `printf`. I used this code to calculate the `total` and then store it in the index `matrix[i][NUM_INPUTS]`.
Now, I *slightly* changed your code and loop for storing the total in the matrix itself becomes:

```c
for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
    GPA = (matrix[i][1] + matrix[i][2] + matrix[i][3] + matrix[i][4]) * 2.5;
    if (GPA == 50) {
        GPA += 3;
    }
    grades = (matrix[i][5] + matrix[i][6] + matrix[i][7] + matrix[i][8] + matrix[i][9] + matrix[i][10]) * 0.67;
    total = GPA + grades + matrix[i][11];

    matrix[i][NUM_INPUTS] = total;
}
```

Now, this made it easy for me to implement a basic `Bubble Sort` algorithm to sort your `matrix`:

```c
int k;
for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < number_of_students - 1; j++) {
        if (matrix[j][NUM_INPUTS] > matrix[j + 1][NUM_INPUTS]) {
            double temp;
            for (k = 0; k < NUM_INPUTS + 1; k++) {
                temp = matrix[j][k];
                matrix[j][k] = matrix[j + 1][k];
                matrix[j + 1][k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, since the matrix itself has been sorted, we will simply print the final matrix:

```c
for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
    printf("%d. %g | %g\n", i + 1, matrix[i][0], matrix[i][NUM_INPUTS]);
}
```

Note: One more thing you can do (totally for input validation) is write an if statement, that would check if the user input for number of students is in the range of `1 <= number_of_students <= MAX (50)`, if it is greater than that, it would cause an `out-of-bounds exception` or a Buffer Overflow.

```c
if(number_of_students > MAX || number_of_students <= 0) {
    printf("Invalid number of students");
    return 1;
}
```

I hope you understood what I wrote and would love if you'd upvote as this is my first answer here.

Here's the full source code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    const int MAX = 50;
    const int NUM_INPUTS = 12;
    int number_of_students, i, j;
    double matrix[MAX][NUM_INPUTS + 1], GPA, grades, total;

    printf("Number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_students);

    if(number_of_students > MAX || number_of_students <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid number of students");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Input students: ");
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_INPUTS; j++) {
            scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Firstly calculating the total and storing it in the final index of the matrix:
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
        GPA = (matrix[i][1] + matrix[i][2] + matrix[i][3] + matrix[i][4]) * 2.5;
        if (GPA == 50) {
            GPA += 3;
        }
        grades = (matrix[i][5] + matrix[i][6] + matrix[i][7] + matrix[i][8] + matrix[i][9] + matrix[i][10]) * 0.67;
        total = GPA + grades + matrix[i][11];

        matrix[i][NUM_INPUTS] = total;
    }

    // Sorting this based on total:
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < number_of_students - 1; j++) {
            if (matrix[j][NUM_INPUTS] > matrix[j + 1][NUM_INPUTS]) {
                double temp;
                for (int k = 0; k < NUM_INPUTS + 1; k++) {
                    temp = matrix[j][k];
                    matrix[j][k] = matrix[j + 1][k];
                    matrix[j + 1][k] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    printf("Final list:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++) {
        printf("%d. %g | %g\n", i + 1, matrix[i][0], matrix[i][NUM_INPUTS]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello. This is exactly what I needed. I tried doing this myself but I didn't know how to add my total value to the matrix. Since I am a new user, I can't upvote yet, but I will as soon as I get 15 reputation. Thanks once again.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `scanf()` in your code. [A good reason why](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).